# Making two dataframes interact following certain criterias in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe, which I call `group`. It comprises a lot of companies registries:

```
group:

                 Ratio                       a
companyid                                       
25             5.13271             1.18846e+06
86             1.19454             2.29432e+09
312            165.962                  547000
...
316            6.77336              3.9294e+07
330            3.56741              4.8953e+07
405        0.000429348             2.32911e+06
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the 10 companies with the the largest `a` in `group`. For that I'm using the following:

```
pdf=group.sort('a',ascending=False)[:10].astype(object)
```

It gets me the following dataframe:

```
pdf:

                 Ratio                       a
companyid                                      
2844          0.782216             4.34118e+09
86             1.19454             2.29432e+09
2177         0.0386724              8.6625e+08
1407           2.08113             3.84293e+08
3094           1.25491              3.3353e+08
1099          0.671924              2.6757e+08
877           0.443107             6.20865e+07
330            3.56741              4.8953e+07
1147           16.9933              3.9313e+07
316            6.77336              3.9294e+07
```

Note that this dataframe has 10 companies inside, and it should remain with 10. However, I only want it to count with companies which `Ratio` is in the range between -3.95 and 6.40. And I need to do that dinamically. So, what I need to do:

a) Create a way to check if there is a company with `Ratio` out of the range (in this case, the 1147 and 316 are out of range) and take those companies out of `pdf`:

For that I'm using the following and it is working ok:

```
for i in pdf['Ratio']:
    if i>6.40:
        b=i
        position=(pdf['Ratio'][pdf['Ratio'] == b]).index
        print(position[0])
        pdf=pd.DataFrame.drop(pdf, position[0])

    if i<-3.95: #check the ones over max and exclude them
        position=(pdf['Ratio'][pdf['Ratio'] == i]).index
        print(position[0])
        pdf=pd.DataFrame.drop(pdf, position[0])
```

b) Insert the next companies of "Group", in the order of `a` (from largest to smallest), in order to make `pdf` contain 10 companies again. Ok, I can do that with:

```
if 10-(len(pdf.index))>0:
    select=(group).sort('a',ascending=False)[10:10+10-(len(pdf.index))].astype(object)
    pdf=pd.concat((pdf,select))
```

The problem is that after this interaction I will need to check if the new companies are with `Ratio` in the range between 6.40 and -3.95 again. And if there is any company out of range, I will have to take it out and put the next ones in the line.

And if any of those next ones are out of range, I will have to do that again and again and again. I think it might be something with a `while` loop, however I'm quite a beginner and I'm not very familiar with using `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but wouldn't you be fine just excluding all the invalid ratio rows before taking your 10 largest a-values?

e.g. do:

```
valid_ratios = group.query('Ratio > -3.95 & Ratio < 6.40')
```

before you use:

```
pdf=valid_ratios.sort('a',ascending=False)[:10].astype(object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Max Power! Actually you didn't misuderstand. The way I was going was a thousand times more complicated. Thanks for enlightening!